# Creating a Column Link in an Interactive Report -Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, parameters, hyperlink, oracle-apex

I am using Apex 20.1.0.00.13, trying to create link on a column of a Classic Report.

I have followed the step to create the link for a column and redirect it to a page in the same application as the steps below :

> To create a link to another page, in the Link Builder - Target dialog:
>   Type - Select Page in this Application.
>   Page - Specify the target page number.
>   Set Items - Select a Name and Value to specify session state for an item.
>   Clear Session State, Clear Cache - Specify the page numbers on which to clear cache. To specify multiple page, enter a comma-delimited list of page numbers.
>   Rest Pagination - Select Yes to reset pagination for this page.v
>   Advanced, Request - Specify the request to be used.
>   Click OK.

But when I am setting the item and values to specify session state for an item, the Set Items : Name doesn't populate the columns, it appears blank, Could someone let me know where I am going wrong.

I am trying to achieve a link from page 1 say a row with dept no - 2, to be directed to page 2 with details of dept 2 . Is there any other way to do it. Since its a column and not an item I am unable to pass it as a parameter to the next page.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right; there are no "items" here, you have to create hyperlinks within the report.

Suppose that this is classic report's query:

```
with test (id, name) as
  (select 1, 'Google' from dual union all
   select 2, 'Yahoo'  from dual union all
   select 3, 'Bing'   from dual
  )
select 
  id, 
  '<a href="' || case 
                  when name = 'Google' then 'https://www.google.com'
                  when name = 'Yahoo'  then 'https://www.yahoo.com'
                  when name = 'Bing'   then 'https://www.bing.com'
                end
              || '" target="_blank">' || name || '</a>' as link
from test
order by name;
```

Go to `LINK` column's properties and set "Escape special characters" to "No". Run the report; everything should work OK.

---

If - as you say - use it to navigate to another page in your application and set some items to some values (from the IR), then you'd do something like this:

```
SELECT   
  'f?p=&APP_ID.:217'            || 
  ':&APP_SESSION.::NO::P217_ID' || 
  ':' || r.id
  as link, ... 
FROM my_table r ...
```

In other words: it navigates to page 217 and passes `r.id` column value into `P217_ID` item which is located on page 217.

`link` column from such a query can be referenced when creating a link column. It would be a

- link to custom target
- target type = URL
- URL = `#link#` (literally, type `#link#`)

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot,    The snippet by you works fine for URLs, but I want to map the items from one column of a page to another column in another page. How do I specify the href for the columns.

Comment: As my second page is an interactive report, It is unable to find an item. Is it possible to link a column to another column in another page?

Comment: I added some more info; have a look, please.

Comment: Since my page 217 is an IR, a region ,  not an item, so I am unable to lookup for the item P217_ID  in the first page. I am linking column data of one report to another report, so no items involved- both are columns @Littlefoot

Comment: Page 217 is an IR, but - can't you create a page item which will contain data transferred by that URL, and then use that P217_ID in IR's WHERE clause?

Comment: that helped. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could change and merge these two pages into one Master-Detail page. This way you could use the built in lookup function.